# WPF - How to duplicate Controls / a whole grid by pressing a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, duplicates, controls

I am new to WPF and I am trying to make a control that will expand my form with a specific controls each time i hit it until it reaches maximum of 7 times.

this is the form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXpZP.png

```
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Insert a file or expand to insert more file at once." Margin="0 10"/>

        <!-- Add File -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="File Name:" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="0 10" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Test" Height="20" Width="50" />
        </Grid>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllChildren}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}" />

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <Grid Margin="0 10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 10 0" Content="Save"   />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Expand" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0.2,0,123.6,0.2" Click="Button_Click"   />
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Cancel"  />
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I try to duplicate the  grid until it reaches maximum of 7 duplications.

how do I make this through the Button Event handler code ?

Comment: Set your grid as a `UserControl` or `DataTemplate`, and put it in a Panel (like `StackPanel` or `ListView`) that you can bind to a `ObservableCollection`. When you hit the button, just add a element to your `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an illustration of my comment. I try to kept the ViewModel as simple and generic as possible, so it should look empty. It is up to you to modify it, and eventually put some DataBinding (I would recommend it).

Let us know if you need something more specific. The XAML:

```
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Insert a file or expand to insert more file at once." Margin="0 10"/>

        <ListBox  Name="DynamicList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileM}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="File Name:" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="0 10" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Test" Height="20" Width="50" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <!--Since I don'T have any information about it, I removed the ItemsControl part-->
        <Grid Margin="0 10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 10 0" Content="Save"   />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Expand" Click="Button_Click"   />
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Cancel"  />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class FileM
{
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<FileM> ListFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileM>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DynamicList.ItemsSource = ListFiles;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ListFiles.Count<7){ListFiles.Add(new FileM());}
    }

}
```